# Trying to load circles from external json file and, add number labels centred in circles, using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html

Good day.

I have the following code, which simply displays some circles, based on the included data.

I am trying to do two things;

first, get the data from an external, but local, json file
second, place numbers (white) in the centre of each circle, as per the "label" in the json data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

CODE:

HTML:

```js
var jsonCircles;

jsonCircles = [{
    "x": 68,
    "y": 61,
    "radius": 20,
    "color": "green",
    "label": "0"
}, {
    "x": 361,
    "y": 60,
    "radius": 20,
    "color": "green",
    "label": "1"
}, {
    "x": 360,
    "y": 311,
    "radius": 20,
    "color": "green",
    "label": "2"
}, {
    "x": 65,
    "y": 310,
    "radius": 20,
    "color": "green",
    "label": "3"
}, {
    "x": 112,
    "y": 28,
    "radius": 20,
    "color": "green",
    "label": "4"
}]

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(jsonCircles)
    .enter()
    .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        return d.radius;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d.color;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Three Little Circles (Using JSON)</title>


</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Demo using External Data (but Local):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-opeoml?file=index.html

---

## Explanation

for perfectly centered <text> in svg, you can use

CENTER ORIGIN X `text-anchor       = "middle"`

CENTER ORIGIN Y `dominant-baseline = "middle"`

---

and after that, you can set the `x` and `y` position of the text same as circle one.

```html
...

<g>
    <circle cx="361" cy="60" r="20" fill="green"></circle>
    <text    x="361"  y="60" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white">
      1
    </text>
</g>

...
```

---

#### Demo Example:

[image]

---

#### Source Code:

```js
const jsonCircles = [
  { x: 68, y: 61, radius: 20,color: "green", label: "0", },
  { x: 361, y: 60, radius: 20, color: "yellow", label: "1", },
  { x: 360, y: 311, radius: 20, color: "red", label: "2", },
  { x: 65, y: 310, radius: 20, color: "orange", label: "3", },
  { x: 112, y: 28, radius: 20, color: "green", label: "4", },
];

const svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg");
const circleContainersgGroup = svgContainer.selectAll("g").data(jsonCircles).enter().append("g");
const circles = circleContainersgGroup.append("circle");
const texts = circleContainersgGroup.append("text");

svgContainer.attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

/* Circle Attributes */
circles
  .attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("r", d => d.radius)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color);

texts
  .attr("x", d => d.x).attr("y", d => d.y)
  .text(d => d.label)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")              // center X svg
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")        // center Y svg
  .attr("fill", "white");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Three Little Circles (Using JSON)</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

---

### Another EVEN better way

```js
const jsonCircles = [
  { x: 68, y: 61, radius: 20,color: "green", label: "0", },
  { x: 361, y: 60, radius: 20, color: "yellow", label: "1", },
  { x: 360, y: 311, radius: 20, color: "red", label: "2", },
  { x: 65, y: 310, radius: 20, color: "orange", label: "3", },
  { x: 112, y: 28, radius: 20, color: "green", label: "4", },
];

const svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg");
const circleContainersgGroup = svgContainer.selectAll("g").data(jsonCircles).enter().append("g");
const circles = circleContainersgGroup.append("circle");
const texts = circleContainersgGroup.append("text");

svgContainer.attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

/* by using this line of code, 
  you refactored the code 
  in a way to not write multiple times 
  the same coordinate on both of them 
*/
circleContainersgGroup.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);

/* Circle Attributes */
circles
  .attr("r", d => d.radius)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color);

texts
  .text(d => d.label)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")              // center X svg
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")        // center Y svg
  .attr("fill", "white");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Three Little Circles (Using JSON)</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

---

#### if you want to get data from a server/external, you can use

```js
d3.json("https://YOUR_LINK.json").then(data => {
   // your D3 code
}
```

---

#### if you want to get data from external file but *LOCAL*

1. create a file with the extension `.js` like `externalData.js` in you

```js
// this is "externalData.js"
export default [
  { x: 68, y: 61, radius: 20,color: "green", label: "0", },
  { x: 361, y: 60, radius: 20, color: "yellow", label: "1", },
  { x: 360, y: 311, radius: 20, color: "red", label: "2", },
  { x: 65, y: 310, radius: 20, color: "orange", label: "3", },
  { x: 112, y: 28, radius: 20, color: "green", label: "4", },
];
```

2. go to you main js file where there is the d3js code and use `import` like this:

```js
// this is the main js file "./script.js"

import externalData from "./externalData.js"

const svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg");
// change here the parameter passed in d3's`.data()` method to the imported data
const circleContainersgGroup = svgContainer.selectAll("g").data(externalData).enter().append("g");
const circles = circleContainersgGroup.append("circle");
const texts = circleContainersgGroup.append("text");

svgContainer.attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000);

circleContainersgGroup.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);

/* Circle Attributes */
circles
  .attr("r", d => d.radius)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color);

texts
  .text(d => d.label)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")              
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")        
  .attr("fill", "white");
```

3. in html to make IMPORT/EXPORT syntax to work. add `type="module"` to your script tag

```html
<script 
   type="module" 
   src="./script.js"
></script>
```

## DEMO WITH EXPORT/IMPORT:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-opeoml?file=index.html

Comment: Thanks a MILLION to all those who responded.  It works GREAT !

Comment: How do I input the data from an external (but local) json file ?

Comment: @Paul see my edited answer now to have a better idea